# Here Maps showing console error on loading

Tags: heremaps

I am using heremaps since last few years, recently we noticed some errors in console window , it seems like here api unable to load venues. https://signature.venue.maps.api.here.com/venues/signature/v1?xnlp=CL_JSMv3.0.17.0&app_id=XXXXX&app_code=XXXXXXXXXXXXX
Though application runs fine. Currently we are using version 3.0

I am not sure how to resolve this issue.